# Krakend Integration with Datadog

Tags: datadog, krakend

I try to send metrics form krakend to datadog. Both are deployed using Docker compose like here https://www.krakend.io/docs/telemetry/datadog/ . I can see agent on infrastructure list and measures like memory cpu etc are there but no metrics from krakend. I checked krakend logs and no errors there. Any idea how to Configure krakend?

Answer (score 0):

If you see the agent on Datadog then the component is working, the only thing that is probably missing in your config is enabling the metrics. Using the same config in the link you are providing, you would need to add the `enabled_layers` like follows:

```json
{
    "$schema": "https://www.krakend.io/schema/krakend.json",  
    "version": 3,
      "extra_config": {
        "telemetry/opencensus": {
          "sample_rate": 100,
          "enabled_layers": {
            "backend": true,
            "pipe": true,
            "router": true
          },
          "reporting_period": 0,
          "exporters": {
            "datadog": {
              "tags": [
                "gw"
              ],
              "global_tags": {
                "env": "prod"
              },
              "disable_count_per_buckets": true,
              "trace_address": "localhost:8126",
              "stats_address": "localhost:8125",
              "namespace": "krakend",
              "service": "gateway"
            }
          }
        }
      }
}
```

If this does not work, share your configuration and logs with the level `DEBUG`, there's probably something else going on